# Reading files frame by frame

Tags: matlab, for-loop, point-clouds

I have a folder containing .ply files. I want to read them and plot them like an animation. Initially i am trying to read the files and plot individually using the following code:

```
testfiledir = 'Files\';
plyfiles = dir(fullfile(testfiledir, '*.ply'));

for k=1:length(plyfiles)
   FileNames = plyfiles(k).name;
   plys=pcread(FileNames);
   pcshow(plys)
end
```

But while running the script i get the error:
`Error using pcread (line 51)
File "val0.ply" does not exist.
Error in read_pcd (line 6)
   plys=pcread(FileNames);`

val0.ply is one my first frame which is read in the variable 'plyfiles'

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: `plys=pcread(['Files\',FileNames]);` ? You need the path, not just the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a datastore it is much easier and will keep track of everything for you. E.g.

```
ds = fileDatastore("Files/","ReadFcn",@pcread,"FileExtensions",".ply");
```

then you can read the files from it using `read` or `readall`, e.g.

```
while hasdata(ds)
    plys = read(ds);
    pcshow(plys)
end
```

It is slightly slower than if you can make the optimal implementation, but I prefer it big-time for its ease.

Comment: Thanks. It is efficient. However, i am not getting all the frames - just like the above code (it fixes my error but no output). So how do i save a gif file using all the frames? Trying to do something like this: [https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495-how-can-i-create-animated-gif-images-in-matlab]